# export array list to excel xlsx in react js

Tags: reactjs, excel, arraylist, export-to-excel, xlsx

I'm trying to export my table to an excel file
, so I created a function after fetching my data that convert from array to excel, I worked but it does not export all data
this is an example of what am getting
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vgUh.png)
so as you can see the last three columns are empty, I think the problem is that  the date is array data , but I don't know-how
this is my code :

```
import {
    GridToolbarContainer,
    gridVisibleSortedRowIdsSelector,
    gridFilteredSortedRowIdsSelector,
    gridVisibleColumnFieldsSelector
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";


const CustomToolbar = () => {

    const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
    const getFilteredRows = ({ apiRef }) => gridVisibleSortedRowIdsSelector(apiRef);
    const handleExport = (options) => apiRef.current.exportDataAsCsv(options);
    const fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8";
    const fileExtension = ".xlsx";
    const fileName = "myfile";
    const buttonBaseProps = {
        color: "primary",
        size: "small",
    };

    // const arrayToExcel = (a) => {}
    const Export = (a, fileName) => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(a);
        const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
        const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
        const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
    };

    const myfiltredRows = (a) => {
        const filteredSortedRowIds = gridFilteredSortedRowIdsSelector(apiRef);
        const visibleColumnsField = gridVisibleColumnFieldsSelector(apiRef);
        let data = filteredSortedRowIds.map((id) => {
            const row = {};
            visibleColumnsField.forEach((field) => {
                row[field] = apiRef.current.getCellParams(id, field).value;
            });
            return row;
        });
        let m = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        data.map((d) => { (delete d._check_, delete d.action) })
        console.info(data)
        Export(data, fileName)
        // arrayToExcel(data)
    };

    return (
        <GridToolbarContainer>
            <Button
                {...buttonBaseProps}
                onClick={(e) => myfiltredRows(getFilteredRows)
                }> Filtered rows</Button>
        </GridToolbarContainer>
    );
}
```

this is the function that converts my array to excel

```
const Export = (a, fileName) => {
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(a);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code snippet you provided, it seems that the issue you are facing is that some columns that were arrays are appearing empty when you export the data to Excel.

One possible reason for this could be that Excel is not able to recognize the array data type and is therefore displaying the column as empty. To fix this, you can try converting the array data to a string before exporting it to Excel.

Here's an example of how you can modify the code to convert array data to a string before exporting:

```
const Export = (a, fileName) => {
  // Convert any array data to a string before exporting
  const newData = a.map((item) => {
    const newItem = { ...item };
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
      if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
        newItem[key] = item[key].join(", ");
      }
    });
    return newItem;
  });

  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(newData);
  const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
  const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
  const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
};
```

In this modified version of the code, we're using the map function to create a new array where any array values are converted to a string using the join function. We then use this new array to create the Excel sheet.

Note that this assumes that you want to join the array values with a comma and space. You can modify this as needed to match your specific use case.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).